# Placing a text exactly at the bottom left of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I would like to get the exact layout of the picture I uploaded. I want the text to be exactly at the bottom left of the page. the class of the document is : `\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}`

If I do it manually (by adding approximate spaces), it is just not clean enough, and I cannot get to the bottom of the page...

I also wonder about the points in the picture, I need them to be exactly aligned (from the left part), Do I have to create a table for this purpose (with left arguments for both columns)?!

Thank you if you can help me.

[image]

Comment: please see [atbegshi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) or  [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)  packages

Comment: at bottom left of text area or of page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment `defenseinfo` below inserts a flush-left `tabular` with the dots you require; `\vfill` pushes content to the bottom of the text block. You can specify an optional argument to `defenseinfo` which will define the width of the dots "column" (default is `10em`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\newenvironment{defenseinfo}[1][10em]
  {\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{~\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\vfill

\begin{defenseinfo}
  Defense date \\
  President \\
  Jurors \\ \\
  Others
\end{defenseinfo}

\end{document}
```

As it stands this is not added to the title page, as the title page is set on its own. However, one can modify the creation to include the `defenseinfo` information.